# How do I concatenate a String literal and a String variable in Java?

Tags: java, string

```
String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(new java.util.date());
upload.uploadfile("192.168.0.210", "muruganp", "vm4snk", "/home/media/Desktop/FTP Upload/+date+"_RB.zip"", "/fileserver/filesbackup/Emac/+date+"_RB.zip"");
```

uploadfile is a function which uploads the file 10-20-2010_RB.zip to the server location.

But since I do have the string "date" in my path, few errors like illegal start of expression occurs.

If I try the same as below, the program works fine.

```
upload.uploadfile("192.168.0.210", "muruganp", "vm4snk", "/home/media/Desktop/FTP Upload/20-10-2010_RB.zip", "/fileserver/filesbackup/Emac/20-10-2010_RB.zip");
```

For some reasons, I am in a compulsion to insert the string in the file path. How can I attain the end result ? Kindly advise.

Comment: just a curiosity: who takes care of replacing the `date` occurence inside the string you use for the name? I hope it's something custom because using `+date+` won't do the trick.

Comment: Thanks everyone..... Your answers are absolutely correct for resolving the required task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting syntax errors because you don't have quote marks correct in the string concatenation. You need to change

```
upload.uploadfile("192.168.0.210", "muruganp", "vm4snk",
    "/home/media/Desktop/FTP Upload/+date+"_RB.zip"",
    "/fileserver/filesbackup/Emac/+date+"_RB.zip"");
```

to

```
upload.uploadfile("192.168.0.210", "muruganp", "vm4snk",
    "/home/media/Desktop/FTP Upload/"+date+"_RB.zip",
    "/fileserver/filesbackup/Emac/"+date+"_RB.zip");
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe, you want `"/home/media/Desktop/FTP Upload/" + date + "_RB.zip"` instead of `"/home/media/Desktop/FTP Upload/+date+"_RB.zip""` ?  I'm not exactly sure how this even compiles.

Also, you have month and day switched around in your SDF pattern. (So, date would be converted to `10-20-2010` string and not `20-10-2010`.)

Answer (score 3):

I see

```
"/home/media/Desktop/FTP Upload/+date+"_RB.zip""
```

It should be

```
"/home/media/Desktop/FTP Upload/"+date+"_RB.zip"
```

(I think it's a copy/paste typo since it won't work)